# Within a wardrobe made for drag

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> I might be found within a flag,
>   or within a wardrobe made for drag.
>
> You can find me on your hand,
>   in a pet that hunts through woodland.
>
> I can be found on most sites,
>   look for me past the twirling tights.
>
> Read me wrong, I'll make you sleep,
>   you cannot measure me for deep.
>
> A country if you squint your eye,
>   I end when you eventually die.

**What am I?**

Comment: I don't have an explanation for all phrases, but are you *pattern* or *line*?

Comment: @GustavoGabriel Nope!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Attempt #2:

Less of a stretch this time

You are a

> Span?

Reasoning:

**I might be found within a flag,**

> <strike>Some flags are used to mark the span of a bridge. Other flags may depict the land of the state, or their territorial span. Or they include formation dates to indicate their span of existence. (This one's probably wrong)</strike> Star-**Span**gled Banner refers to a specific flag.

**or within a wardrobe made for drag.**

> **Span**gles are a thing, right? -- Answer is spandex/spanx

**You can find me on your hand,**

> Span: The distance between thumb and little finger when fully extended. Mine is 9" +/- 1/8".

**in a pet that hunts through woodland.**

> Cocker **Span**iel

**I can be found on most sites,**

> I'm no web developer, but the `<span>` tag is commonly used I think? I don't know how you could say most sites though.

**look for me past the twirling tights.**

> <strike>Is Spanx a common brand of tights?</strike> Past tense of spin (twirl) is span.

**Read me wrong, I'll make you sleep,**

> Span backwards is naps.

**you cannot measure me for deep.**

> A span measures a unit of distance, not depth. (Although thats a tad arbitrary, there might be a better answer here)

**A country if you squint your eye,**

> Spain?

**I end when you eventually die**

> Lifespan is over upon death.

---

#### Attempt #1:

Bit of a stretch, but here goes:

You are a

> Pole?

Questionable reasoning:

> **I might be found within a flag,** -- Some flags fit around a flagpole instead of simply hanging on them
>  **or within a wardrobe made for drag.** -- Many wardrobes have horizontal poles for hanging clothes
>  **You can find me on your hand,** -- The latin for a thumb is *pollex*?
>  **in a pet that hunts through woodland.**  -- Isn't there a type of polish hunting dog?
>  **I can be found on most sites,** -- Most government sites have a flagpole
>  **look for me past the twirling tights.** -- Many practicing ballet rely on a horizontal pole for balance/stretching
>  **Read me wrong, I'll make you sleep,** -- Replace the oʊ sound with an ɪ sound and you get pill. Some pills make me sleep at least.
>  **you cannot measure me for deep.** -- I might measure a poles length or diameter, but probably not it's depth.

Comment: In regards to the explanation for **Look for me past the twirling tights**: Not necessarily $-$ most ballet practicing takes place by using a *barre*.

Comment: interesting take on it, but yeah bit of a stretch there

Comment: Maybe the second attempt gets a little closer?

Comment: Nice work! Right answer, wrong interpretation of some of the lines though: #6 or spandex was actually meant for #2. Rethink #1 and #6 for a bit and then I'll mark you as correct! Mind removing your first attempt? it makes for a lot to scroll through.

Comment: More confident on #1, unlike #6. Grasping there. Sorry about the length, I reverted user477343's edit to be what I originally had, should be more compact.

Comment: Right-o, think about the *past* part though for #6, also, make sure to @ me so that way I know when you update or respond back. I didn't even realize that you updated your answer at first. Just happened to scroll down and see

Comment: @paige-meinke See, I want to say spanner, as in a wrench you turn to tighten something, but I would not describe that as twirling and I don't know how that first in with the past. Some people dislike the @ due to the notification.

Comment: @PaigeMeinke I'm dumb

Comment: @PaigeMeinke was that update incorrect?

Comment: Yep! Well Done!!